# How to center placeholder text in both Safari and Chrome?

Tags: css

I've got an input field in which I've given the placeholder text a smaller font than the inputted text itself.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLWKaM)

I used this css for that:

```
input {
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  font-size: 12px;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  font-size: 12px;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  font-size: 12px;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

What happens in Safari however is that that placeholder text is more at the top of the input field and in Chrome that placeholder text is more at the bottom. In both Safari and Chrome the input text itself is vertically centered. How do I make the smaller placeholder text vertically centered in BOTH Safari and Chrome as well?

Comment: You can try using padding instead of a height. Placeholder styling is pretty limited though. If you want fine control i would use a pseudo element instead of native placeholder text and absolutely position it where you want.

Comment: @SamratV I wish to have a large 30px font size for the text that is typed and s smaller 12px font size for the placeholder text

Comment: @GifCo padding wouldn't help as I can't use a different padding for Safari then I would for Chrome. They are both using the same webkit css

Comment: Why would you want to use a different padding? You said you want it to look the same on both?

Comment: @GifCo That's my point. In Safari the placeholder text is pretty much centered, but in Chrome it's lower. I could add padding at the bottom to make it go up, but what would make it so up in Safari as well. Then it would be centered in Chrome, but too high in Safari this time.

Comment: No remove height all together. Use padding to create the height you want. Thats how people usually style inputs not setting explicit height.

Comment: That still doesn't work. [link]https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Pvpwdj In Safari that placeholder text still is nice and centered, but in Chrome still too low

Comment: Well like I said styling placeholder text is not ideal. Either just make your placeholder text the same font-size as the actual input text. Or if your design really really has to have a smaller placeholder text you are going to have to create it manually .

Answer (score 1):

```
input::placeholder{
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
}
```

Comment: That's horizontal centering, not vertically

Comment: you can using line-height for vertical